# Question about the following proof in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I started reading the book "Mixed Finite Element Technologies" by Peter Wriggers and Carsten Carstensen, and I have a question about the following. Here is the setup:

[image]

Then, the authors prove the following claim:

[image]

What I do not understand is the part where I underlined in red.

How do I know that such $y$ exists?

All I know is that there is some $y$ which is in $Y$, but not in $R_2(Range(A_1))$, and I feel that the closedness of $Range(A_1)$ has to do with it, but I do not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R_2~\text{Range}(A_1) \subsetneq R_2 Y^* = Y$, there is some nonzero $z\in Y$ with $z \notin R_2~\text{Range}(A_1)$ (where I am freely identifying $Y$ with its dual). Since $\text{Range}(A_1)$ is closed, and $R_2$ is an isomorphism, $R_2~\text{Range}(A_1)$ is also closed. Then it is a closed proper subspace of a Hilbert space, and so $z$ has a nonzero orthogonal projection to $R_2~\text{Range}(A_1)$, i.e. $z = x + y$, where $x \in R_2~\text{Range}(A_1)$ and $y \perp R_2~\text{Range}(A_1)$.

Comment: I see. I guess that $y \neq 0$ since otherwise $z\in R_2Range(A_1)$ contradicting $z\not\in R_2(RangeA_1)$?

Comment: Precisely. You can do this thing whenever you have a closed proper subspace of a Hilbert space.

Comment: Also, is it always the case that isomorphism preserves a closed set? Or is it special to this Riesz map $R_2$?

Comment: It is always the case. An isomorphism of Hilbert (or Banach) spaces is actually a homeomorphism if you view them as topological spaces, and homeomorphisms preserve closedness (and openness).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: By the way, it just came to me that the map $R_2$ also maps a subspace to a subspace?

Comment: Yes, but that's true of all linear maps.